# The prediction time of spark matrix factorization

Tags: python, apache-spark, recommendation-engine

I have simple Python app.
take ratings.csv which has user_id, product_id, rating
which contains 4 M record then I use Spark AlS and save the model, then I load it to matrixFactorization.

my problem with method predicts which takes more than one second to predict the rating between user and product.
my server is 32 G and 8 cores.
any suggestion how I can enhance the prediction time to be less than 100milisecond.
and what the relationship between a number of records in the data set and the prediction time.

Here is what I am doing :

```
spark_config = SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '32g'), ('spark.cores.max', '8')]) 
als_recommender.sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_config) #training_data is array of tulips of 4 M record 
training_data = als_recommender.sc.parallelize(training_data) als_recommender.model = ALS.trainImplicit(training_data, 10, 10, nonnegative=True) 
als_recommender.model.save(als_recommender.sc, "....Ameer/als_model") 
als_recommender_model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(als_recommender.sc, "....Ameer/als_model") 
als_recommender_model.predict(1,2913)
```

Comment: We'd need to see your code.

Comment: spark_config = SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '32g'),
                                           ('spark.cores.max', '8')])
als_recommender.sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_config)
#training_data is array of tulips of 4 M record
training_data = als_recommender.sc.parallelize(training_data)
als_recommender.model = ALS.trainImplicit(training_data, 10, 10, nonnegative=True)
als_recommender.model.save(als_recommender.sc, "....Ameer/als_model")
als_recommender_model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(als_recommender.sc, "....Ameer/als_model")
als_recommender_model.predict(1,2913);

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you do not want to have to load the full model everytime you need to answer.

Depending on the model update frequency and in the number of prediction queries, I would either :

- keep the model in memory and being able to answer to queries from there. For answer < 100ms, you will need to measure each step. Livy can be a good catch but I am not sure on its overhead.
- output the top X predictions for each user and store them in DB. Redis is a good candidate as its fast, values can be a list