# Caching user and product latent features in PySpark to enhance the prediction time

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to cache the product features and the user features to enhance the Spark `MatrixFactorizationModel` prediction time.

what I did:

1. Train the model ALS .
2. Save the model.
3. load the model and cache the user features and the product features .

code snippet :

```
spark_config = SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '8g'), ('spark.cores.max', '4')])`

sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_config)

self.als_recommender = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc,Path)
self.als_recommender.userFeatures().cache()
self.als_recommender.productFeatures().cache()
```

and I got the same warnings and the prediction is slow:-

```
WARN MatrixFactorizationModelWrapper: User factor is not cached. Prediction could be slow.
WARN MatrixFactorizationModelWrapper: Product factor is not cached. Prediction could be slow.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a follow up for an earlier question of yours,  [The prediction time of spark matrix factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818401/the-prediction-time-of-spark-matrix-factorization) .

Here is the trick, you'll need to perform an action on the cached featured for it to work before performing the predictions (in **scala**):

```
als_recommender.productFeatures().cache()
als_recommender.productFeatures().count()
als_recommender.userFeatures().cache()
als_recommender.userFeatures().count()
```

Like this you'll force Spark to load data in cache.

But even then you'll not get **faster** predictions... (<100ms.)

I advise you to read my following posts to understand the main challenges of what you are trying to achieve :

- [Time/Space Complexity challenge in Recommendation System ?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13279/solution-for-in-time-space-complexity-challenge-in-recommendation-system/13488#13488)
- [Recommendation System to integrate with an Android app](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15499/recommendation-system-to-integrate-with-an-android-app/15504#15504).

**EDIT:** The code above doesn't work with **pyspark** since the model actually uses JavaRDD under the hood.

```
loaded_model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "target/tmp/myCollaborativeFilter")
loaded_model.userFeatures().cache()
print("user features count : {}".format(loaded_model.userFeatures().count()))
print("user features cached : {}".format(loaded_model.userFeatures().is_cached))
# user features count : 4
# user features cached : False

loaded_model.productFeatures().cache()
print("product features count : {}".format(loaded_model.productFeatures().count()))
print("product features cached : {}".format(loaded_model.productFeatures().is_cached))
# product features count : 4
# product features cached : False
```

To **solve this**, we would need to cache the underlying `JavaRDD` :

```
loaded_model._java_model.userFeatures().persist(sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK())

loaded_model_storage_lvl = loaded_model._java_model.userFeatures().getStorageLevel()
print("use disk : {}".format(loaded_model_storage_lvl.useDisk()))
print("use memory : {}".format(loaded_model_storage_lvl.useMemory()))
print("use off heap : {}".format(loaded_model_storage_lvl.useOffHeap()))
print("deserialized : {}".format(loaded_model_storage_lvl.deserialized()))
print("replication  : {}".format(loaded_model_storage_lvl.replication()))
# use disk : True
# use memory : True # ==> It is persisted indeed in memory and disk (line above)
# use off heap : False
# deserialized : True
# replication  : 1
```

**PS:** This solution is needed for **spark <2.+** as in newer versions of Apache Spark this had been added to the model. New versions of Apache Spark allows us controling storage level for intermediate and final stages (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b1e639ab09d3a7a1545119e45a505c9a04308353/python/pyspark/ml/recommendation.py#L144)).

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Any Way , i the cache is not working, how i can check if the cache working or not?

Comment: okay , then what the solution for caching , caching does not works with pyspark ?

Comment: There is actually no solution for that. I haven't tested with newer versions of Spark as this might be dealt with internally. Personally, I cache those features working with Scala Spark.

Comment: I'm not sure of your requirements nevertheless and I don't even know why you are trying to do that.

Comment: In cases you are trying to accomplish what you described in your earlier questions, allow me to say that you are not taking the good approach.

Comment: what iam trying to do is to build recomondation system for accomodations using als and matrix factorization.

then after training the model and save it (using implicit feedback).

we load it using matrixfactorization.load function

then we try to predict the rating between the user and the accomodation using predict function which is slow (more than 100 ms)

note that i will use predictall  function which take one user and more than 200 accomodation id (more than 2.5 second)

Comment: As stated in the answer for your earlier question along with the answers that I have shared in this current one. You should do your predictions before hand to serve them in time.

Comment: Spark ML/MLlib isn't fit for your use case as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152656/discussion-between-ameer-salah-aldeen-and-eliasah).

Comment: about the early prediction ,is it good to cache the product features and the user features in redis then we can get the product features and the user features and multiply them to get the rank ?

Comment: That's not what you want to cache. Saving the ALS model isn't made for this purpose. You want to save predictions.

Comment: but is it good to save prediction for more than 10 million user and more than 1 m accommodation

Comment: You need to find the trade off. This is more or less opinion based

Comment: @AmeerSalahAldeen I've updated my answer but I still don't recommend that you use it the way you intend to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152674/discussion-between-eliasah-and-ameer-salah-aldeen).